# Error : Symbol not found in java method charAt(int)

Tags: java

My program contains this line:

```
char A= K.charAt(i);
```

But, when I executed this, I'm getting an error saying:

```
error: cannot find symbol
      char A= K.charAt(i); 
               ^
symbol:   method charAt(int)
location: variable K of type String[]
```

What wrong did I do?

Comment: K is a `String[]` (string array), while `chatAt(int)` is a method belonging to `String`. You can get a string from the array by using `K[index]`.

Comment: Add your entire program. Maybe you are trying to access undeclared variable.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What does a "Cannot find symbol" compilation error mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25706216/what-does-a-cannot-find-symbol-compilation-error-mean)

Comment: Please read about a [mcve] and edit the question accordingly

Comment: Oh and PS: it's always good to stick to the Java Naming Conventions. Variables always start with lowercase. So `A` and `K` should be `a` and `k` respectively.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Form the error message, it says variable `K` is an array of type `String`. So to get the value from an array use this syntax, `K[i]`. Once you get a `String` from the array, you can use `sampleString.charAt(i)` to get a char at index `i`.

Example:

```
String[] K = {"abc","def","ghi"};
String sampleString = K[1]; // sampleString -> def
char firstChar = sampleString.charAt(0) // firstChar -> d
```